# How to distinguish a closing event is triggered by “x” on the left of a tabbed window or “x” on the left top to close all windows

Tags: cocoa, macos-sierra

With the latest macOS, the tab feature introduced,

my app needs to support this.

Here is the thing, I don't know how to distinguish the closing event like the title I said.

What I expect is when I click the "x" on the left of a tabbed window, it should close this single tab window.

And when I click the "x" on the left top of the whole window, it should close all the tabbed window in this main window.

I have implemented these two methods, when I click the "x" on the left top if the whole window, it can close all tabbed window, and when I didn't merge them into a window, I can close it one by one.

But when I merge them into a window and click "x" on the left of each tab window. it still close all the tabbed window. So I think the root cause is I can't tell the tab closing and window closing event.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Are you passing window object in close method ?

Comment: @ParagBafna, whatever these two "x" you click, the "windowShouldClose" will be called and, the window instance will be sent, so how to tell this window instance is for the two "x" action